# how to group list elements having the same name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to regroup elements having the same name,i tried this code:

```
l=[0,1,1,1,3,3]
lo=[[2,1,5],[2,8,9],[5,9,7],[4,6,9],[7,9,5],[2,5,6]]
ss=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    for j in range(i+1,6):
        if l[i]==l[j]:
            b=[lo[i],lo[j]]
            print(b)
            ss.append(b)
            print('////',ss)
           break

        else:
            b=[lo[i]]
            print('****',b)
            ss.append(b)
            print('/*/*/',ss)
            break

print('ss:',ss)
```

i expected the result

```
ss: [[2,1,5],[[2,8,9],[5,9,7],[4,6,9]],[[7,9,5],[2,5,6]]]
```

but it gives:

```
ss: [[[2, 1, 5]], [[2, 8, 9], [5, 9, 7]], [[5, 9, 7], [4, 6, 9]], [[4, 6, 9]], [[7, 9, 5], [2, 5, 6]]]
```

Comment: What does "having the same name" mean? There are no names in your code. Please explain the logics behind your groupings better.

Comment: at the first list l=[0,1,1,1,3,3] names list ;
i want output to be a list  of list 
[2,1,5]
[[2,8,9],[5,9,7],[4,6,9]]
[[7,9,5],[2,5,6]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip` the two lists into a sequence of tuples so that you can use `itertools.groupby` to group the tuples based on the values from `l`:

```
from itertools import groupby
[[s for _, s in g] for _, g in groupby(zip(l, lo), lambda t: t[0])]
```

This returns:

```
[[[2, 1, 5]], [[2, 8, 9], [5, 9, 7], [4, 6, 9]], [[7, 9, 5], [2, 5, 6]]]
```

Comment: for sure ,i m new here .
thanks for ur help again .